# Passing JSON data in bootstrap-table

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongoose, bootstrap-table

Bootstrap-table is not working as expected. Doesn't fetch the data from data-url. I have passed the url which holds JSON data. Please suggest how to solve this issue. Have included the index.js below which fetches the data from table organizations

```js
app.get("/organizations", function(req, res) {
  Organization.find({}, function(err, allOrganizations) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.send(allOrganizations);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.12.1/bootstrap-table.min.css">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.12.1/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified Locales -->
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.12.1/locale/bootstrap-table-zh-CN.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table data-toggle="table" data-url="/organizations">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-sortable="true" data-field="name">Name</th>
      <th data-field="location">Location</th>
      <th data-field="contact">Contact</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: As i said bootstrap-table doesn't fetch the data from url @JamesZ

Comment: Well you didn't actually say that, you edited it into the question after my comment, but at least it's better now

Answer (score 0):

You could you use [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) to bring in the data into your Front-End.
Then display it as belows:

```
//display the data
const displayData = (orgs) => {
    //here you can get table by giving it id
    //if its the only table, then you could
    const table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
    let res = '<tbody>'

    orgs.map(org => {
        res += '<tr>'
             + '<td>' + org.location + '</td>'
             + '<td>' + org.contact + '</td>'
             + '</tr>' 
    })
    res += '</tbody>'
    table.innerHTML += res;

}

//fetch the data from the endpoint
const fetchData = async () => {
    const url = 'http://localhost:3000/organizations' //here enter your app URL and port correctly
    const res = await fetch(url)
    const orgs = await res.json()
    displayData(orgs)
}

window.onload = fetchData()
```